# Set a grouped UITableView to start at a given section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad

I have a grouped UITableView that has basic data inside it, but I would like to start the UITableView at a certain section when the app loads, can this be achieved?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - use the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView. Using the index path you specify which section and which row you would like to scroll to. Presumably you would like to see it at the top of the table so in the method call specify `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`.

Comment: cool, thanks, but *when* do I call this? Im a little confused as to where in the loading lifecycle this code should be called?

Comment: viewWillAppear: (in the view controller managing your table view) would be a good time if you want to start the table view at a certain point when the view appears.

Comment: I get the error: `-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: section (1) beyond bounds (0).` but can assure you my table has 3 sections. Are you sure `viewWillAppear` is the right place?

Comment: here is my code: `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection: 1] 
               atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
               animated:YES];`

Comment: it should work if you explicitly do [tableView reloadData]; before the scroll - unless the table is loaded the section you want to go to may not exist.